# Cannot assign to read only property on deep copied object

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

I am using angular 9 and ngrx 9

I have a selector that do like this :

```
    this.store$
      .pipe(select(SettingsStoreSelectors.selectNavigationSettings), take(1))
      .subscribe((settings: SettingsStoreModels.INavigationSettings) => {
        let copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(settings));
        this.settings = copy.vrMapSettings;
      });
```

This is the only place `settings` is assigned in this component

In the component I then have a checkbox that edit a setting property

```
      <mat-checkbox
        class="setting-input"
        *ngIf="viewer"
        (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
        (change)="onSettingChange(settings, true)"
        [(ngModel)]="settings.depthTestAgainstTerrain"
      >
        {{ "MAP.SETTINGS.DEPTH_TEST_AGAINST_TERRAIN" | translate }}
      </mat-checkbox>
```

This keeps triggering

> core.js:4117 ERROR TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'depthTestAgainstTerrain' of object '[object Object]'

But I don't understand anymore what to do. I deep cloned my store property, I want to edit to resubmit an action but it's not possible. why...

**EDIT : actually I found out the reason why but I do not understand how to use it correctly then.**

I deep clone the object like above from my selector

When a setting change, I dispatch an action to change the setting object in the store : this action setting object reference the same object that is used by the component.

```
this.store$.dispatch(new SettingsStoreAction.SetNavigationSettings({ settings: { vrMapSettings: settings } }));
```

Which call this reducer :

```
const SET_NAVIGATION_SETTINGS = (state: State, action: featureAction.SetNavigationSettings) => {
  return {
    ...state,
    navigation: {
      ...state.navigation,
      ...action.payload.settings,
    },
  };
};
```

But then, if I edit again, since the store reference directly the setting object of the component, it trigger the error....

If I deep clone here too

```
this.store$.dispatch(new SettingsStoreAction.SetNavigationSettings({ settings: { vrMapSettings: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(settings))} }));
```

The it works...

But if I have to create small action for EVERY property of settings, or deep clone for EVERY dispatch/selection of the store, there is going to be a HUGE flaw in the performance...

am I using it correctly ?

if need more information please comment I will provide.

Comment: can you share type of this.settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, a state should be mutated only via actions. In you case, if the settings object has a lot of properties, it might be inconvenient to create a different action for each of the properties. A copying of the settings looks like a solution but deep object copying complexity depends on the object size.

I can suggest you use [immer](https://github.com/immerjs/immer) to create copies of the settings. Instead of copying the whole object it reuses all its unchanged parts that works [much faster](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/docs/performance).

```html
...
<mat-checkbox
  class="setting-input"
  *ngIf="viewer"
  (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
  (change)="onDepthTestAgainstTerrainChange($event)"
  [checked]="settings.depthTestAgainstTerrain">
  {{ "MAP.SETTINGS.DEPTH_TEST_AGAINST_TERRAIN" | translate }}
</mat-checkbox>
...
```

```js
@Component(...)
export class MyComponent {
  ...
  onDepthTestAgainstTerrainChange(change: MatCheckboxChange) {
    const patchedSettings = produce(settings, draft => {
      // draft remembers all the changes you've made and produces
      // new immutable state based on these mutations, but takes all
      // unchanged parts of the original object
      draft.depthTestAgainstTerrain = change.checked;
    });

    this.store$.dispatch(new SettingsStoreAction.SetNavigationSettings({
      settings: { vrMapSettings: patchedSettings}
    }));
  }
}
```

Or you can create an action which accepts a patch function, like:

```js
  onDepthTestAgainstTerrainChange(change: MatCheckboxChange) {
    this.store$.dispatch(new SettingsStoreAction.PatchNavigationSettings(sttingsDraft => {
      sttingsDraft.depthTestAgainstTerrain = change.checked;
    }));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to share declaration of `settings`, looks like it has a readonly flag.

to fix it you can make this signature writable:

```js
export declare type Writable<T> = {
  -readonly [P in keyof T]: T[P];
};

class Test {
  public settings: Writable<TypeYouNeed>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

These state mutations in a reducer are actually increasing the performance.
It's faster than a (unneeded) rerender of a component, you could make use of the `OnPush` pipe because the reference of the state will change which will only cause a rerender when it's actually needed.

The docs of Redux has a [performance page](https://redux.js.org/faq/performance#performance), which can also be applied to NgRx.

If you don't like to update state this way, there's immer. I actually wrote an immer wrapper around an NgRx reducer. See [ngrx-etc](https://github.com/timdeschryver/ngrx-etc).
NgRx also provides the ngrx-entity package which has some helpers to update the state.